# I want to make the button visible on one page by closing another page by clicking the cross button

Tags: java, jquery, .net

I have a button on the page and when I click that button another page open as a pop up and button is hided but when I close that popup page I `want that button to become visible again`. How can I do that?

Comment: Please show the code of what you are saying. than I can tell you what to do to make it visible again.

Answer (score 0):

you take the two functions:

```
function dissableBtns()
{

window.document.frm.name1.disabled=true;
window.document.frm.name2.disabled=true;
  }
function enableBtns()
{
window.document.frm.name1.disabled=false;
window.document.frm.name2.disabled=false;

}
```

this functions call when you want disable or enable: